# Javascript expression not understood

Tags: javascript, operators, jsx

I´m new to React and Js and  I would like to understand this line of code (It is Js inside of the JSX):

```
<h5 className="recipes__title">
  {item.recipe.label < 20 ? `${item.recipe.label}` : `${item.recipe.label.substring(0, 25)}...` }
</h5>
```

Anyone knows how to read and understand it?

Thank you!

Comment: comparison, ternary, string interpolation

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h5 className="recipes__title">            //An html header
                                           //Containing... 
  {
    item.recipe.label < 20 ?               // If the item.recipe.label is less than 20 then...

`${item.recipe.label}`                     // the label
: `${item.recipe.label.substring(0, 25)}   //else the first 25 characters of the label followed by 
  ...`                                     // the string "..."     
}
</h5>
```

You can find out about the ternary operator (which is an expression conditionally resolving to one of two expressions) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

You can find out about template literals (which are strings which can contain javascript to resolve) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. JSX part:

```
<element>
{ // You can put your Javascript here but mostly inline script. }
</element
```

> 2. `${...}`

This is a string template introduced in ES6. Its used to build string. `${}` means you want to process JS, variable name or function called.

> 3. substring(0, 25)

This is a part that is checking if the label is of max 25 characters. If not, its picking first 25 characters and then adding ellipsis(`...`) after it.

#### Reference

- [String Template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)